# Arduino. Инфракрасный (ИК) сигнал. Как передать фотодиоду сигнал нажатия кнопки на пульте от телевизора

Tags: c, arduino

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Не совсем еще разбираюсь в ИК сигналах, но на картинке подробно описал, что я хочу делать. С помощью приемника Ик сигнала принял сигнал с кнопки пульта, теперь хочу этот сигнал присвоить другой кнопке, на другой плате. Где я чайник?

Comment: Что значит "присвоить другой кнопке"? Укажите что конкретно не получается. Да, и код здесь принято вставлять текстом, а не скриншотами.

Comment: Акцент тут в другом, неважно про какую кнопку... Я правильно передаю значение полученного сигнала в irsent?

Comment: Так попробуйте скомпилировать и запустить.